# Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows-vista, 64-bit, virtualbox, 32-bit

I've got virtualbox, I've got a linux iso. and when I go to start my virtual machine and install linux, it says "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU". What do I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest option is to download an x86 ISO, as you're unlikely to give more than 4GB of RAM to a VM. Especially if your host OS is 32-bit, running a 64-bit VM will be very slow.

Comment: +1 Good advice as to **why** trying to virtualize 64 bit on a 32 bit OS might be painful.

Answer (score 2):

You will either need to set the Guest OS mode (in Virtual Box) to x64 as it is currently only emulating a 32 bit CPU, or you can download a 32bit Linux iso instead of a 64 bit one.